# WP Query using tax_query & meta_query

Tags: wp-query, functions

I have a custom post type called events.

I have a custom taxonomy called issueEvent.

I have several ACF fields on the taxonomy. The one I have to query by is a checkbox.

I want to query 3 specific taxonomy items via ACF field AND slug. This is what I have so far:

```
    $a = array(
    'post_type'         =>  'events',
    'relation'          =>  'AND',
    'meta_query'        =>  array(
        array(
            'key'       =>  'type',
            'value'     =>  'Archived Event',
            'compare'   =>  'LIKE'
        )
    ),
    'tax_query' =>  array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'      =>  'issueEvent',
            'field'         =>  'slug',
            'terms'         =>  array('june-2019','april-2019','february-2019'),
            'operator'      =>  'LIKE'
        )
    ),
);
$b = new WP_Query($a);
```

I have tried both the standard WP Query (see above, loop not included), and get_terms. The current loop as seen above does not show any results within the loop.

I hope this makes sense, I need some guidance. Thank you

Comment: Have you confirmed that the tax query on its own pulls in posts, and the meta query pulls in post too? I also see you put a top level `relation` key in your arguments, but there is no such key according to the documentation, can you ellaborate on that? Also I see you used `LIKE`, can you expand on that too? Update your question with that information by using the edit link/button. Also, your post meta key `type` is incredibly generic, are you absolutely sure it doesn't have a prefix of some kind to prevent clashes? Is there a reason this was in post meta and not a taxonomy?